# WebRTC practice: The icecandidate cannot be added

Tags: node.js, html, webrtc

I added the IceCandidate after completing the offer and answer, but it still calls errors: 'RTCPeerConnection': the icecandidate cannot be added. This is part of my code:

```
else if (data.user_type == 'signaling') {
  if (!rtcPeerConn)
    startSignaling();
  var message = JSON.parse(data.user_data);
  if (message.sdp) {
    rtcPeerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp),
        function () { // if we received an offer, we need to answer
      if (rtcPeerConn.remoteDescription.type == 'offer' && myUserType=="doctor") {
        rtcPeerConn.createAnswer(sendLocalDesc, logError);
      }
    }, logError);
  } else {
    rtcPeerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this part of the code, except that you're not passing an error callback to `addIceCandidate`, so I'm a bit puzzled where the error you mention would be coming from. This doesn't seem answerable in its present form (and you haven't actually posed a question).

Comment: try printing out the `message.candidate`, may be it is undefined or not the data you are expecting

Comment: You do a check on `message.sdp` to determine if the message contains an sdp. You assume all other messages are ICE candidates, are you sure that's how your signaling mechanism works? Because you usually need way more message types than just sdp and ice.... Could the error come from a message that is neither an sdp nor an ice message?

Comment: I make a judgement to make sure the ICE candidates will enter the 'else' block,but it still show the same error.I am going crazzy!